# lightGallery 1.2 with jQuery 1.11.3 shows endless spinner and JS error, what is wrong?

Tags: jquery, gallery, lightgallery

I have the following setup using jquery 1.11.3 and the new release 1.2 of lightgallery (https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightGallery) installed by bower. I tried several variants with and without the selector e.g. the following, but always the gallery opens (ok), but shows below JS error and a spinning symbol. What is wrong with that?

```
// include the js and css ...
<script>
    (function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.multiSRC ul').lightGallery({
                selector: "li"
            }); 
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

and

```
<div class="ce_rsce_cl_gallery first block">
    <h2>Vestibulum mollis.</h2>
    <div class="field singleSRC">
        <div class="inner">
            <figure class="image_container">
                <img src="assets/images/d/unsplash_528e297be299b_1_thumb-224ccacd.jpg" alt="" class="" height="250" width="250">
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field multiSRC">
        <div class="inner">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <figure class="image_container">
                        <a href="files/upload/photo-1426174840074-541ae41efdb9.jpg" data-lightbox="lb208875">
                            <img src="assets/images/2/photo-1426174840074-541ae41efdb9-71ccd312.jpg" alt="" class="" height="125" width="125">
                        </a>
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure class="image_container">
                        <a href="files/upload/photo-1425934398893-310a009a77f9.jpg" data-lightbox="lb208875">
                            <img src="assets/images/4/photo-1425934398893-310a009a77f9-ba3b2cd4.jpg" alt="" class="" height="125" width="125">
                        </a>
                    </figure>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This error occurs:

```
21:04:43.287 TypeError: src is undefined1 lightgallery.js:393:12
```

which is

```
var youtube = src.match(/\/\/(?:www\.)?youtu(?:\.be|be\.com)\/(?:watch\?v=|embed\/)?([a-z0-9self\-]+)/i);
```

Do I do something wrong? Or is some bug hiding in the lightgallery script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selector object should have `data-src/href` attribute with large version url of your image/video.. So you can just change selector value to `li a`

```
$('.multiSRC ul').lightGallery({
    selector: "li a"
});
```

Here is the working demo. http://jsfiddle.net/amL2Lpqa/1/

Comment: Yes. Great! Works as expected! Thank you